# Memory Leak happens in Xamarin Forms Android while using Bitmap

Tags: memory-leaks, bitmap, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, out-of-memory

While using bitmap in Xamarin Forms Android I'm getting out of memory error while loading images which are of higher than the usual size.

```
void getImage() {
    -------     
    imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmapFromViewUpdated(_view), (int) width, (int) height, true));
    tempView = imageView;
    --------
}
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(final View view) {
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight()));
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    final Bitmap bitmap_ = Bitmap
            .createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap_);
    view.draw(c);

    return bitmap_;
}

Bitmap getBitmapFromViewUpdated(final View view) {
    if (view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0)
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    else
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight()));
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    final Bitmap bitmap_;
    if(viewWidth>0 && viewHeight>0) {
        bitmap_ = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(viewWidth,
                        viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    else
    {
       bitmap_= Bitmap
                .createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap_);
    view.draw(c);

    return bitmap_;
}
```

I have tried `android:largeHeap=true`, can achieve the result while using that but I need to know how to fix with bitmap resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these two links for efficient bitmap management in xamarin android

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5716/disposing-of-bitmaps-properly

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/

GoodLuck!

Comment: Have checked this links but needed how to get the resized one in view.

Comment: Actually if you give it your bitmap it will give you the compressed and resized bitmap itself Please check the second link try implementing the scenario itself @Rabhia